# Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'void'

Tags: java, spring-boot, foreach, neo4j, get

I'm stuck in this error that shows up " Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'void' " after I tried to fetch data from a list of an object with the help of foreach I don't understand what's the problem,
this is where the problem show up

```
public void sendMailOwner(VacacionRequest PaidRequest) {
        CollaboratorDTO validator = OrganizationalUintService.findValidator(collaboratorTransformer.entityTranferToDTO(PaidRequest.getCollaborator()));
        EmailService.sendSimpleMessage(PaidRequest.getCollaborator().getEmail(),
                "EverHoliday",
                " Bonjour "+PaidRequest.getCollaborator().getFirstname()+" "+PaidRequest.getCollaborator().getLastname()+","
                + "\n Votre demande de Congé payé du date "+PaidRequest.getDatesRequest().forEach((p)->p.getStartDate)+"au"+PaidRequest.getDatesRequest().forEach((p)->p.getEndDate)+" est en attente de validation par : "
                        +validator.getLastname()+" "+validator.getFirstname()
                + " \n Cordialement.");
    }
```

`PaidRequest.getDatesRequest().forEach((p)->p.getStartDate)` as you can see i want to fetch all startdate from datesrequest list

this is DatesRequest Model

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.GeneratedValue;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Id;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Node;
@Node
public class DatesRequest {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;    
 private LocalDate startDate;
 private LocalDate endDate;
 private double duration;
public DatesRequest(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, double duration) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.duration = duration;
}
public DatesRequest() {
}
public LocalDate getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}
public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
public LocalDate getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}
public void setEndDate(LocalDate endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}
public double getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
public void setDuration(double duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

and this is where we declared DatesRequest in  PaidRequest Model

```
public PaidRequest(LocalDate requestDate, String statut, String typeOfTime, List<DatesRequest> datesRequest,
        Collaborator collaborator, String description, double balanceUsed,String justification) {
    super(requestDate, statut, typeOfTime, datesRequest, collaborator);
    this.description = description;
    this.balanceUsed = balanceUsed;
    this.justification = justification;
}
```

Comment: The `forEach(Consumer)` method returns `void` (i.e., has no return value). What are you actually trying to concatenate to the string?

Answer (score 0):

As long you concatenate strings the both arguments of '+' operator must be strings. But `PaidRequest.getDatesRequest().forEach((p)->p.getStartDate)` this is not a string but void, if you want to get it as comma separeted string use something like:

`String.join(",", PaidRequest.getDatesRequest().map((p)->p.getStartDate))` (remember to collect to list)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to *join* String with void datatype.

`PaidRequest.getDatesRequest().forEach` is returning void datatype.

If you want to join `getStartDate` to your string, then I would recommend extract it to Array or list & then join it later.

Answer (score 0):

as cited in the other answer I was trying to join string type with void datatype
so as a solution I tried to convert localdate startdate to string with format

```
public void sendMailOwner(VacacionRequest PaidRequest) {
        List<DatesRequest> datesRequests = PaidRequest.getDatesRequest();
        String StartDate = datesRequests.stream().map(DatesRequest::getStartDate).map(date -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        String EndDate = datesRequests.stream().map(DatesRequest::getEndDate).map(date -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        CollaboratorDTO validator = OrganizationalUintService.findValidator(collaboratorTransformer.entityTranferToDTO(PaidRequest.getCollaborator()));
        EmailService.sendSimpleMessage(PaidRequest.getCollaborator().getEmail(),
                "EverHoliday",
                " Bonjour "+PaidRequest.getCollaborator().getFirstname()+" "+PaidRequest.getCollaborator().getLastname()+","
                + "\n Votre demande de Congé payé du date "+StartDate+"au"+EndDate+" est en attente de validation par : "
                        +validator.getLastname()+" "+validator.getFirstname()
                + " \n Cordialement.");
    }
```

and that how it worked